# SUM 3 different "CASE" columns with three different totals

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm new to this so I'm sorry if I asked this question wrong. But I'm trying to get 4 different SUM's from my table that uses 4 different cases. But I want the id to be listed only once with the totals. I'll show you what I have, and what I'm trying to get. Please help if possible.

```
    SELECT schools.name, articles.competition_place,

    Case when articles.competition = 'yes' and competition_place = '1' then int '100'
       when articles.competition = 'yes' and competition_place = '2' then int '60'
       when articles.competition = 'yes' and competition_place = '3' then int '20'
    ELSE 0 end AS "Competition_Score",

    Case when articles.out_reach = 'yes' then int '30'
        ELSE 0 end AS "out_reach_Score",

    CASE when schools.school_id is not null then int '5'
        ELSE 0 end as "article_score",

    (Case when articles.competition = 'yes' and competition_place = '1' then int '100'
        when articles.competition = 'yes' and competition_place = '2' then int '60'
        when articles.competition = 'yes' and competition_place = '3' then int '20'
        ELSE 0 end) +
    (Case when articles.out_reach = 'yes' then int '30'
        ELSE 0 end) +
    (CASE when schools.school_id is not null then int '5'
        ELSE 0 end) as "total_score"
    from articles
    join clubs on articles.club_id = clubs.club_id
    join schools on clubs.school_id = schools.school_id
```

[My table that I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kFEj.png)

And this is what I'm trying to get.

[This is the table I'm trying to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rpawq.png)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

use aggregation and group by

```
SELECT schools.name, articles.competition_place,

sum(Case when articles.competition = 'yes' and competition_place = '1' then int '100'
   when articles.competition = 'yes' and competition_place = '2' then int '60'
   when articles.competition = 'yes' and competition_place = '3' then int '20'
ELSE 0 end) AS "Competition_Score",

sum(Case when articles.out_reach = 'yes' then int '30'
    ELSE 0 end) AS "out_reach_Score",

sum(CASE when schools.school_id is not null then int '5'
    ELSE 0 end) as "article_score",

sum((Case when articles.competition = 'yes' and competition_place = '1' then int '100'
    when articles.competition = 'yes' and competition_place = '2' then int '60'
    when articles.competition = 'yes' and competition_place = '3' then int '20'
    ELSE 0 end)) +
sum((Case when articles.out_reach = 'yes' then int '30'
    ELSE 0 end)) +
sum(CASE when schools.school_id is not null then int '5'
    ELSE 0 end)) as "total_score"
from articles
join clubs on articles.club_id = clubs.club_id
join schools on clubs.school_id = schools.school_id
group by schools.name, articles.competition_place
```

Comment: That gets me a little closer. I'll keep trying but instead of articles.competition_place I tried using total_score but it doesn't work. Is it because I can't use the columns I create with case?

Comment: I've actually tried the sub query. I'll try it again. Thanks for the advice!